# How can I create a draganddrop wrapper inside a table row, that can represent the whole row

Tags: css, drag, vaadin, treetable

When I use treetable in Vaadin, it is working fine drag and drop the whole row when click the left and right blank ereas. but that is not user friendly, I wanna create a draggable layout inside the row, let's say the 1st component of the each row, that when clicking it, the whole row is selected and can be draged and dropped to reorder.

The thing is I can create a vertical layout with wrapper doing that, but drag mode is only for its component or the wrapper itself, and when doing the drag action, it doesn't actually showing the whole row is moving, which may confuse the clients. What can I do to make it looking like I am dragging the whole row, similar with the one you drag the blank area of each row? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there currently is no way for adding a wrapper that would extend the entire row instead of just one cell. To do this you'd need to extend the client-side implementation of Table (VScrollTable) and this is not something I would recommend as it is quite complex.

I do think that what you describe should be possible in core Vaadin (without using drag & drop wrappers), so could you please file a ticket at [dev.vaadin.com](http://dev.vaadin.com)? And please attach a small application showing the problem to make it easier for us to see the problem and fix it.

Anyways, in order for you to get it working today I'd suggest that you change your UI design a bit and for example borrow drag handles from iOS. By this I mean that you could add an icon that suggests "draggable" as a background-image in the first cell (or in the row header cell of each row) that encourages the user to grab the row there, where it *is* "empty" and dragging works. This way the user might not be too confused if dragging only works reliably in some parts of the rows.